# Ruth 'the wife of Mahlon' or Elimelech?

Tags: exegesis, ruth

Why is Ruth called 'the wife of Mahlon' (Ruth 4:10) whereas in the beginning of the story she is the wife of Elimelech?

Comment: Where exactly is Ruth called the wife of Elimelech??

Comment: Elimelech was the husband of Naomi ([Ruth 1:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ruth+1%3A1-3&version=NRSV)), Ruth's (first) mother-in-law, not the husband of Ruth herself.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden and curiousdanii  Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa, as the priest says in the old Latin rite in the Catholic Church.  I made a HUGE blooper by careless reading of 'Ruth'.

Comment: A small blooper. But you can delete the question if you don't want your blooper to remain public.

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken:

> The man’s name was Elimelek, his wife’s name was **Naomi**, and the names of his two sons were Mahlon and Kilion...They married Moabite women, one named Orpah and the other Ruth. - [Ruth 1:2,4 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ruth%201&version=NIV) [*Emphasis added*]

So it is *Naomi*, not Ruth who was the wife of Elimelech; the verse you cited gives the more specific information that **Ruth married Mahlon** whereas chapter 1 leaves it open as to whether it was Mahlon or Kilion that she'd married.